# how to intentionally configure a web server to return 500

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, express

I am seeking for guidance.
My goal is to intentionally create a 500 to test if the website can properly show our customized page.

I have a web site hosted on website (docker on ec2 with nginx) behand a load balancer.
I am aware that I can configure LB to return a fixed response code based on path.

Nginx
I wonder what is the best practice to test such test case?
I am thinking I can purposely miss configure the nginx to make a 500 page, or do something like this
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04

Express server:
I am wondering how to test to see if our express server catches 500 and displays a custom error page?

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Why LB is not enough for your needs? You can use AWS CLI or SDK to automate it.

Comment: Check this documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: thank you nickolay for your reply. I guess my thoughts was all over the place. Yes you are right LB works but I think what I really wanted is to see express handles error in action and display a rendered page... Thank you Ahmed for the reply and the link.

Comment: *if our express server catches 500* seems imprecise in its terminology and/or objective.  You should simply need to *throw an exception* deliberately in your code and verify whether the server responds as you intend.  An HTTP 500 response is the *result* -- not the *cause* -- so deliberately generating a 500 response does not sound like what you should be attempting to do... and indeed may it not result in the same behavior as an actual uncaught exception since you can deliberately generate any response you want and most environments should just return it unaltered.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the comment.